# how to add multiple arrays in plist file programmatically in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, plist

I want to create plist file with multiple array and array as Root type.I can add multiple array in dictionary but I want to add all array in one array programmatically.How is it possible to create plist file programmatically and write array data into it.Please guide me and give some sample links.Thanks.
Here is my code to add array in dictionary :

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Demo.plist"]; 

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Demo" ofType:@"plist"]; 

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
}

firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"15-5-123",@"15-5-12",nil];
secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"TestFiling",@"TestFiling",nil];
thirdArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"15132561",@"15135601", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:firstArray forKey:@"firstArray"];
[dictionary setObject:secondArray forKey:@"secondArray"];
[dictionary setObject:thirdArray forKey:@"thirdArray"];

[dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:NO];

NSDictionary *dictionary1;
dictionary1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"dictionary1 %@",dictionary1);
```

this code is working fine for dictionary but i want to add arrays in array.

Comment: You say you can add arrays in a dictionary, show that code and how you tried modifying it for an array of arrays

Comment: Here your [Answer][1] follow this things.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636524/how-to-write-multiple-arrays-in-plist-in-iphone?rq=1

Comment: @Wain - Please see my edited question. I have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

The first section of your code is fine, you just need to switch the second part to using an array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[array addObject:firstArray];
[array addObject:secondArray];
[array addObject:thirdArray];

[array writeToFile:path atomically:NO];

NSArray *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"array1 %@", array1);
```